# module 'webdriver_manager.driver' has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Someone please help me with this error. It is working when I run without `pytest-bdd` additions.(working with `pytest` framework). But when I create `.features` file and step definition and accessing this, This time I'm facing this issue. Nothing changed in this file while integrating the test structure with `pytest-bdd`.

Trying to execute below code and facing `"module 'webdriver_manager.driver' has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'" error.`

Code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from Utilities import configReader
import logging
from Utilities.LogUtil import Logger

log = Logger(__name__, logging.INFO)


class BasePage:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def click(self, locator):
        if str(locator).endswith("_XPATH"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator)).click()
        elif str(locator).endswith("_CSS"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator)).click()
        elif str(locator).endswith("_ID"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_id(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator)).click()
        log.logger.info("Clicking on an element: " + str(locator))

    def type(self, locator, value):
        if str(locator).endswith("_XPATH"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator)).send_keys(value)
        elif str(locator).endswith("_CSS"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator)).send_keys(value)
        elif str(locator).endswith("_ID"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_id(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator)).send_keys(value)

        log.logger.info("Typing in an element: " + str(locator) + " value entered as : " + str(value))

    def select(self, locator, value):
        global dropdown
        if str(locator).endswith("_XPATH"):
            dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator))
        elif str(locator).endswith("_CSS"):
            dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator))
        elif str(locator).endswith("_ID"):
            dropdown = self.driver.find_element_by_id(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator))

        select = Select(dropdown)
        select.select_by_visible_text(value)

        log.logger.info("Selecting from an element: " + str(locator) + " value selected as : " + str(value))

    def moveTo(self, locator):

        if str(locator).endswith("_XPATH"):
            element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator))
        elif str(locator).endswith("_CSS"):
            element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator))
        elif str(locator).endswith("_ID"):
            element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(configReader.readConfig("locators", locator))

        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        action.move_to_element(element).perform()

        log.logger.info("Moving to an element: " + str(locator))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed to pass driver correctly.

Updated my code by passing the driver . Its working fine now .